# How to handle form.non_field_errors and form.errors?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to display non_field_errors and field errors in different styles. so i did like below

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
   {{ form.non_field_errors }}
   </div>
{% endif %}

{% if form.errors %}
   <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
       {% for field in form %}
          {% if field.errors %}
              {{ field.errors| striptags }}
          {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

but when there is a non field error without any field errors, both sections are displayed.
How can i  display only non field error section if there is no field errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition `{% if form.errors %}` is triggered when there are form errors, including non field errors.

Maybe you can convert the second block to a for loop and place the if condition within:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
             {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is just a very simple example. You can extend and adapt it according to your needs.

EDIT:

even better solution would be to use django-crispy-forms:

http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Don't reinvent the wheel!

EDIT: answer the first comment below

If you really want to display all field errors in a single DIV, for whatever reason you might need that, you could eventually write:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {# first block #}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {# your logic #}
    {% endif %}
    {# second block #}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {# your logic #}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

So if there are only field errors, the non field errors block won't show up.

Comment: i know form.errors include non field errors, how do i display all field errors in a single div tag?

Comment: but the second block will be displayed even if there is no field errors...i don't need to display the second block if there is no field errors

Comment: Yes, you're right. My answer is actually opposite to your question.

Comment: You want to do something specific, but the logic for this should be in my opinion in the view, not in the template. Unfortunately there is nothing like ``form.field_errors``, you should think it out yourself.